# Python extract json structure from html page

Tags: python, html, json, string

in python i'm reading an html page content which contains a lot of stuff.
To do this i read the webpage as string by this way:

```
url = 'https://myurl.com/'
reqq = req.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
reddit_file = req.urlopen(reqq)
reddit_data = reddit_file.read().decode('utf-8')
```

if i print the `reddit_data` i can see correctly the whole html contents.
Now, inside it there's a structure like json that i would like to read and extract some fields from that.

Below the structure:

```
"dealDetails" : {
      "f240141a" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://ccc.com",
         "title" : "ZZZ",
         "type" : "ghi",
      },
      "5f9ab246" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.bbb.com/",
         "title" : "YYY",
         "type" : "def",
      },
      "2bf6723b" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.aaa.com//",
         "title" : "XXX",
         "type" : "abc",
      },
}
```

What i want to do is: find the `dealDetails` field and then for each `f240141a` `5f9ab246` `2bf6723b`
get the egressURL, title and type values.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full `script` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
[nested_dict['egressUrl'] for nested_dict in reddit_data['dealDetails'].keys()]
```

---

To access the values of JSON, you can consider as dictionary and use the same syntax to access values as well.

**Edit-1:**

Make sure your type of reddit_data is a dictionary.

if `type(reddit_data)` is `str`.

You need to do..

```
import ast
reddit_data = ast.literal_eval(reddit_data)
```

OR

```
import json
reddit_data = json.loads(reddit_data)
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion but i get this error: `[nested_dict['egressUrl'] for nested_dict in reddit_data['dealDetails'].keys()]
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: @xXJohnRamboXx Read your json data using `json.loads(your json data)` or `ast.literal_eval(your json data)`

Answer (score 0):

- If you just wanted to know how to access the egressURL, title and the type. You might just wanna read the answer below! Be careful however, cause the following code won't work unless you converted your HTML file *reddit_data* in something like a dictionary ( Modified *shaik moeed*'s answer a tiny bit to also return title and type) :

```
[(i['egressUrl'], i['title'], i['type']) for i in reddit_data['dealDetails'].keys()]
```

- However, If I got it right, the part you're missing is the conversion from HTML to a JSON friendly file. What I personally use, even though it's quite unpopular, is the **eval** function

```
dictionary = eval(reddit_data)
```

This will convert the whole file into a dictionary, I recommend that you only use it on the part of the text that 'looks' like a dictionary! (One of the reason eval is unpopular, is because it won't convert strings like 'true'/'false' to Python's True/False, be careful with that :) )

Hope that helped!